# Looking a generic Python script to add a field and populate the field with conditions

Tags: python, sql, sql-update

I am looking for a script to allow users to add a text field to a .dbf table(e.g. landuse categories) and allow them to input/update the rows basing on what values in the GRIDCODE (numeric categories) field they think should be assigned into text categories.i.e.  if GRIDCODE value is 4, the corresponding field value of landuse/landclass is “forest” etc.

Is there such a script in existence?

Or, do you have something similar that I can customise to create a new script?

The script will accept users' interactive input as parameters passed into the script.

Sincerely, David

Answer (score 2):

When you say dbf table, are you referring to ESRI shape file dbf files, which are in fact dbase files? If so you could implement such a thing pretty easily with the python wrapper for [shapelib,](http://shapelib.maptools.org/) which also supports dbf files.